# Does adding a line impedance stabilisation network reduce the output of buck converter in simulation in LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice, buck, emc, emi-filtering

I have modelled a 48v to 12v buck converter in Ltspice.When I added a LISN the output reduced from 11v to 6.3v but EMI remains the same.Is it okay if output voltage is reduced?[image: LTspice model]

Comment: No it is not OK. What is missing is a big reservoir capacitor from "vlisnout" to GND. You need to feed the buck convertor proper (M1 on), from a low impedance source, not an inductance.

Comment: You really hate that gate, don't you? And mock `C6`.

Comment: Thanks Brian Drummond.That was helpful