# Buck Converter EMI simulation output LTSpice

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, simulation, buck, emc

I am trying to do an elementary EMI analysis on my Buck converter circuit by modelling the LISN circuit. I am using LTSpice for this. The buck converter works when I simply simulate this circuit alone:-

[image: buck]

Here is the waveforms for this circuit:-

[image: waveforms]

But when I try to add the LISN circuit with this I am getting wrong output voltages and thus wrong everything else. What am I doing wrong? I suspect it is something to do with the net labels but I cannot get it right.

[image: lisn]

Waveforms for this:-

[image: waveform2]

EDIT 1:-
I made the suggested changes in the circuit and this is the waveforms I get:-
[image: Vout]
[image: new circuit]
[image: switching node]

Is the Vpwm1 correct? I am getting a wrong switching waveform.

EDIT:2
After several comments, I have realized the problem lies with the LISN circuit, but I don't know how to set the inductors and capacitors of this module. As per Bruce Abbott's suggestion I lowered it to 5uH but still not getting the right common mode and differential mode voltages, although the output voltage is correct. This is a buck converter (12 V to 5 V @200 kHz):-
[image: buck]
Here is the waveforms:-
[image: waveforms]
How do I fix the C6 value and the LISN L & C values? [This is just for simulation on LTSpice, the real PCB is being simulated on ANSYS SIwave)

Comment: It looks like whoever posted the previous answer deleted it. It said the EMC is not something you simulate with a SPICE simulator, but rather with a FEMM or similar. There was also a comment pointing towards a possible [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/529844/95619).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes I'm simulating the actual PCB using ANSYS SIwave,but I thought it better to understand the basics properly using LTSpice. Thank you for the link.

Comment: R1 seems unrealistically low to me. Perhaps it should be 0.05 ohms rather than 0.05 micro-ohms?

Comment: In what way is the switching waveform 'wrong'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The "sw" node voltage waveform should have been like a square wave, like a PWM voltage waveform....but it isn't here

Comment: It is a square wave, but you have 100uH of inductance in the power supply wiring. Look at the voltage across C1 and you will see what is happening. Short out the 50uH inductors and see what happens.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Unfortunately I don't understand. The LISN block is meant to be connected that way right? I shorted the inductors and removed C1, it gave a square wave with few oscillations in the rising edge (since the LISN capacitors were still there). I see from C1 voltage it is getting charged and discharged....but I can't connect the dots. It'll be helpful if you explain a bit. Also,in a buck converter circuit that originally was perfectly satisfying design parameters with output load R=0.5 ohms must be increased to 20 ohms to get same output voltage as before.Why?

Comment: Buck converter draws pulses of current from the power supply. That goes through the inductors and induces voltage across them. To reduce this you need to increase 'bulk' capacitance and/or reduce inductance. If the inductors are part of a filter circuit then reduce the Q and/or change the cutoff frequency.

Comment: @BruceAbbott (This is probably a silly question) The LISN is basically just a filter, which makes the low-frequency noise pass through itself so that the spectrum analyser can see if the product meets the specifications,right? So the "LISN module" L and C components are not fixed values, are they? (Like L3 L2 can be something other than 50uH?)

Comment: Where did you get your LISN circuit from? Here's one that only has a total of 5uH, and seems more suitable for your application (low voltage DC) -  https://www.tekbox.com/product/tboh01-5uh-lisn-cispr-25/

Comment: @SM32 did you get to know where the problem with the LISN was?

Answer (score 1):

When drawing the LISN into your schematic you have to decide where you are placing your GND symbol.

I notice that you have a GND symbol at the bottom of V1 and also in the center of the LISN.  That's not correct because C4 and R5 are connected to GND at both ends.

Also remember that (as things are drawn right now) the reference point for your "out" node is node "n" rather than ground.  So to get the supply output voltage you must measure V(out) - V(n) rather than just V(out) relative to ground.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that GND mistake.I still don't get even the correct switching waveform, although the output seems to be a bit closer to the actual waveform,but yes wrong.Kindly see the edit.