# EMI/EMC Simulation using SMPS Software

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, emc

Assuming I have a complete SMPS simulating circuit using Simplis/Simetrix simulator and all the AC and transient specifications are met. How can I perform an EMI/EMC simulation test using this software?
I have looked around its documentation and I did not find something.

- Which software performs EMI/EMC test simulations of power electronics and in that case is there a way to import the Simplis/Simetrix circuit to that software?
- I found something that may help me on the following site: https://www.edn.com/edn-access-02-03-97-spice-predicts-differential-conducted-emi-from-switching-power-supplie/

Unfortunately, the images and illustrations are deleted, it seams as an obsolete publication. Does anyone have an update, or the original publication? It’s an important document that might help me.

Comment: Simulation-wise, the best tool is a finite element, like FEMM. SPICE is not suited for this. At best, you can try to [model some parasitics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/529844/95619) and see what you get, but that's not a proper testing.

Comment: You can perform conducted emission simulation to a reasonable degree but this applies to any spice software. To a lesser extent you can achieve some relative measure of conducted susceptibility for your circuit. You can also simulate line drop-outs, surges and overloads reasonably well but, you have to know exactly what you are doing and this is probably beyond the scope of any single Q and A on this site.

Comment: @Andyaka, I have found in some books the authors use a trick, so they evaluate the input current signature then they start designing an EMI filter (As a simulation step of course).

Answer (score 1):

For conducted emissions one can implement a model of an EMI test receiver in the simulation (as a postprocessor, taking simulated waveforms) and simulate the same things which one would measure in an experimental setup. A good model description of an EMI test receiver can be found e.g. in sections 2.5.2 and 2.5.3 of [this thesis](https://www.pes-publications.ee.ethz.ch/uploads/tx_ethpublications/Diss_Heldwein.pdf). Fig. 2.18 gives the model overview.

I am not aware of commercial simulation software to be able to do this. However, it is built into the open source simulator [GeckoCIRCUITS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geckocircuits/) but this is not Spice-compatible.

Such a simulation only makes sense if you properly implement all relevant parasitics (e.g. stray inductances, coupling capacitances, ... as mainly defined by PCB design) and the switching behaviour of the semiconductors, and choose small enough simulation time steps.