# Different levels of SPICE models

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, spice, modeling, power-factor-correction

I wanted to model some components operated in a switching boost power converter at LTspice and i realized that different levels are available for power mosfets.

Do all components have different levels or only mosfets have?

Which level is proper for these kinds of circuits (switching power convertes)? And which one is proper for EMI noise analysis?

Comment: All parts might have different levels and thermal effects and EMI requires layout analysis of loop area dI/dt and conducted ripple which might be radiated as well

Comment: @Kamran are you talking about the built in spice mosfet model or a subckt model?

Comment: @Voltage Spike, all the built-in spice MOSFET models of LTspice library are started with **".model name VDMOS"** and don't contain the "level" parameter. but a spice model like **".model IRF130 NMOS(Level=3, .........) "** (however it's not .subckt) contains the "level" parameter. what are these levels for? which one should be used for which purpose? does TLspice support the parameter "level"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a semiconductor device modeling, specifically, referring to MOSFET models, parameter **Level** identifies the model implementation in the hierarchy of device models. The quite exhaustive list in Star-Hspice Manual Chapter 16 enumerates 18 models, most are of IDS (drain-source current) and BSIM (Berkeley Short-channel IGBT model) flavors.

Most of these models are based on lateral MOSFETs with a bulk connection. As a
power MOSFET has a vertical structure without bulk connection, the academia and device manufacturers have developed the models *which accurately portray the vertical DMOS power MOSFET electrical and thermal responses*. I borrowed this phrase from Fairchild's [Application Note 7533 A Revised MOSFET Model With Dynamic Temperature Compensation](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-7533.pdf).

You can read in this document that, rather than semiconductor physics-based or empirical "classical" SPICE models, VDMOS models are macro-models around the Level 1 (Schichman-Hodges) MOSFET model with added resistive, capacitive, inductive and other SPICE circuit elements (like switches). The switches provide a method to precisely model the non-linear capacitance.

These models are further enhanced involving a MOSFET analog behavioral model (ABM) implementation dependent on a SPICE Level 3 IDS empirical model. This enhancement is important for high frequency applications where gate charge losses become significant.

For the power devices, very important is a development in the direction of circumventing the SPICE global temperature definition, providing a means of using the device’s own junction temperature as a self-heating feedback mechanism.

At this moment, the model designation with a Level parameter becomes ambiguous for the power MOSFETS. First, the "classical" definition of the MOSFET parameter Level holds. Second, at least one manufacturer (Infineon) designates the position in their own hierarchy of models with the same word, see Infineon's [Application Note AN 2014-02 Introduction to Infineon’s Simulation Models Power MOSFETs](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_PowerMOSFET_SimulationModels-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46250cc1fdf0151588db5ef1b18), section **3 Definition of Modelling Levels**.

ST Microelectronics developed their own Spice model versions available for Power MOSFETs that implement the self-heating model. See the document [User manual UM1575, Spice model tutorial for Power MOSFETs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1575-spice-model-tutorial-for-power-mosfets-stmicroelectronics.pdf). ST do not use the word Level for designating their six model **versions** in Section **1 Spice model versions**.

When preparing this text, I found an article [A Power MOSFET SPICE Model
with Built-In Model Generator](https://www.highfrequencyelectronics.com/Archives/Aug13/1308_HFE_spice.pdf) By Andre Adrian, eponymous with the method which may be useful for your analysis. I have no hand experience with Andre Adrian's model and only guess what you mean the `"conducted EMI" analysis not radiative`, so I leave it to you to estimate the usefulness of the model for your applications.

To directly answer your questions: in the common usage, only MOSFET models have the parameter *Level*; the power MOSFET model selection should serve your design goals and the documents referenced in my answer can help you in decision making; the EMI noise analysis is not specific for SMPS but may have features that should be accounted when developing your design. It also depends on your design goals.

Comment: This is an excellent answer with a lot of valuable references. The one point, which may be missing, is that the `level` specification is only for monolithic MOSFETs, not for board-level power MOSFETS, which use an entirely different model: `VDMOS` as outlined in the Help file of LTSpice and hinted at by *a concerned citizen* below/above.

Comment: @pfabri Quite the contrary: I'm doing more than simply emphasize the 'standard' usage of the word 'level' for naming the parameter positioning the model in the hierarchy of 'monolithic device' (as you put it) models. In addition, I explicitly elaborate on the ambiguous usage of this "keyword" by Infineon in their Application Note AN 2014-02, section 3 Definition of Modelling Levels.

Comment: Evidently, usage of the 'level' parameter as indicating the position in the hierarchy of 'monolithic devices' is inconsistent with the model of a typical modern power MOSFET with its multiple parallel cells/trenches. But Infineon, in their proprietary power MOSFET models, are defining the parameter with the same name (unfortunately for you and perhaps for other beginner engineers). When your experience develops, your would accommodate yourself to disambiguate this usage.

Comment: Thanks for adding further details, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid none of them are because those models are for monolithic MOSFETs. If you are using LTspice (you have the [ltspice](/questions/tagged/ltspice) tag) then the best `.model` is the VDMOS. However, even this might not suffice if your interest is a detailed analysis, and you may need to use models made with `.subckt` definitions, even if they will be slower to simulate (larger matrix, more elements/nodes). As for EMI, no SPICE is suited for it, try a FEMM-like software. But if you insist, [here's something](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/529844/95619) that may (or may not) help.

Comment: I meant "conducted EMI" analysis not radiative. With that said, is FEMM still suitable for conducted EMI analysis?